# Eliminate duplicated code in nested (classes) unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

So I have some unit tests in NUnit. Tests have structure similar to RSpec/Jasmine tests - bunch of nested classes with inheritance to pass fields down the line.

Here is sample:

```
[TestFixture]
class ControllerTests
{
    private Controller _controller;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _controller = new Controller();
    }

    private class WhenUserIdExistsInSession : ControllerTests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public new void Setup()
        {
            //Preconditions...
        }

        private class WhenUserExistsInDb : WhenUserIdExistsInSession
        {
            [SetUp]
            public new void Setup()
            {
                //Preconditions...
            }

            private class WhenCompanyIdExistsInSession : WhenUserExistsInDb
            {
                [SetUp]
                public new void Setup()
                {
                    //Preconditions...
                }

                private class WhenCompanyExistsInDb : WhenCompanyIdExistsInSession
                {
                    [SetUp]
                    public new void Setup()
                    {
                        //Preconditions...
                    }

                    private class WhenCompanyIsKindaSpecial : WhenCompanyExistsInDb
                    {
                        [SetUp]
                        public new void Setup()
                        {
                            //Preconditions...
                        }

                        [Test]
                        public void SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_1()
                        {
                            _controller.GetCompanyReport();
                            //Some stuff.. 
                        }

                        [Test]
                        public void SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_2()
                        {
                            _controller.GetCompanyReport();
                            //Some stuff.. 
                        }

                        [Test]
                        public void SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_3()
                        {
                            _controller.GetCompanyReport();
                            //Some stuff.. 
                        }
                    }

                    private class WhenCompanyIsTotallyNormal : WhenCompanyExistsInDb
                    {
                        [SetUp]
                        public new void Setup()
                        {
                            //Preconditions...
                        }

                        [Test]
                        public void SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_1()
                        {
                            _controller.GetCompanyReport();
                            //Some stuff.. 
                        }

                        [Test]
                        public void SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_2()
                        {
                            _controller.GetCompanyReport();
                            //Some stuff.. 
                        }

                        [Test]
                        public void SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_3()
                        {
                            _controller.GetCompanyReport();
                            //Some stuff.. 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This may look like a small mess so here is screenshot from R#:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0ukU.png)

As you can see there is a lot of duplicated tests:

- SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_1
- SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_2
- SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_3

Anyone have an idea how to extract these tests to one place AND keep R#/NUnit to see original structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern to extract your tests to one place.

```
public abstract class ContextBase
{
    protected virtual void Act()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void Arrange()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void Cleanup()
    {
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        this.Cleanup();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        this.Arrange();
        this.Act();
    }
}

public class ControllerTests : ContextBase
{
    private Controller _controller;

    protected override void Arrange()
    {
        _controller = new Controller();
    }

    private class WhenUserIdExistsInSession : ControllerTests
    {
        protected override void Arrange()
        {
            base.Arrange();

            //Preconditions...
        }

        private class WhenUserExistsInDb : WhenUserIdExistsInSession
        {
            protected override void Arrange()
            {
                base.Arrange();

                //Preconditions...
            }

            private class WhenCompanyIdExistsInSession : WhenUserExistsInDb
            {
                protected override void Arrange()
                {
                    base.Arrange();

                    //Preconditions...
                }

                private abstract class WhenCompanyExistsInDb : WhenCompanyIdExistsInSession
                {
                    protected override void Arrange()
                    {
                        base.Arrange();

                        //Preconditions...
                    }

                    protected override void Act()
                    {
                        _controller.GetCompanyReport();
                    }

                    [Test]
                    public void SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_1()
                    {
                        //Some stuff.. 
                    }

                    [Test]
                    public void SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_2()
                    {
                        //Some stuff.. 
                    }

                    [Test]
                    public void SomeGranularUnitTestForReport_3()
                    {
                        //Some stuff.. 
                    }

                    [TestFixture]
                    public class WhenCompanyIsKindaSpecial : WhenCompanyExistsInDb
                    {
                        protected override void Arrange()
                        {
                            base.Arrange();

                            //Preconditions...
                        }
                    }

                    [TestFixture]
                    public class WhenCompanyIsTotallyNormal : WhenCompanyExistsInDb
                    {
                        protected override void Arrange()
                        {
                            base.Arrange();

                            //Preconditions...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it won't let R# see original nested structure.